# Lemon Tree baby leaves curling down

Tags: citrus

[image: Citrus Tree]
The plant was fine a couple of days ago until recently I found that its leaves are curling down and is not having any progress in growing.

Comment: I would say: lack of sun, possibly not ideal pH (did you use soil for citruses?) Maybe also over-fertilized And as anticipation of @stormy answer: pot is too large.